# Regex to match strings inside brackets with no spaces around

Tags: regex, spaces, brackets

I'm using the following regex to match strings inside brackets:

```
\((.*?)\)
```

But this matches this:

```
(word)
```

and this too:

```
( word )
```

I need to modify it to only match the first case: words inside brackets with no spaces around: `(word)`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `(word1 word2)`, should this be matched? How about `()`, should it be allowed?

Comment: Yes to `(word1 word2)`. No to just `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to disallow space after the opening parenthesis and before the closing parenthesis:

```
\((?!\s)[^()]+(?<!\s)\)
```

`(?!\s)` and `(?<!\s)` mean "not followed by / not preceded by a space".

The part in the middle, `[^()]+` requires one or more characters to be present between parentheses, disallowing `()` match.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/u6QLTt/1)

Comment: It's worth noting that javascript does not support lookbehind. So depending on the environment, this will or won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
\([^\s()](?:[^()]*[^\s()])?\)
```

`[^\s()]` ensures that the first character isn't a whitespace or brackets (and make mandatory at least one character).

`(?: [^()]* [^\s()] )?` is optional. if it matches, the same character class ensures that the last character isn't a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

• [**Word Boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
\(\b[^)]+\b\)
```