# regex Match string inside brackets which includes (or not includes) spaces

Tags: regex, spaces, brackets

How do you capture a string with regex, that is a) inside round brackets, including the brackets, and b) includes a space (or alternatively *doesn't* include a space) inside the brackets, so to capture  `(test test), ( test), (test )` but not 
`(test)`.

I've found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262902/regex-to-match-strings-inside-brackets-with-no-spaces-around) that uses the expression

```
\((?!\s)[^()]+(?<!\s)\)
```

but with this lookahead/lookbehind rule just looks for spaces that are attached to the brackets. How do you modify that to look for every space inside the bracket?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Should we match `( )` (only space inside the parens)? If so, `/\([^)]* [^)]*\)/` should work.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! :) ```( )``` should be included. For me ```/\([^)]* [^)]*\)/``` includes a regex tester ```( test )``` but not ```(test test)```  or ```( test)``` or ```(test )```, I'm not sure.

Comment: That's odd--it works fine for me. Do you have a link to the regex tester you're using?

Comment: My bad, you're right, VS Code did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/\([^)]* [^)]*\)/`. This matches 0 or more non-closing parentheses characters followed by a space followed by 0 or more non-closing parenthesis characters. So it will match `"(    )"` and `"( )"` but not `"()"`.

```js
const s = "() ( test) (test) (test ) (    ) ( ) ( test ) (t est)";
console.log([...s.matchAll(/\([^)]* [^)]*\)/g)]);
```

Comment: The negated character class will happily match more opening parentheses, which I understand is undesirable.

Comment: It's unspecified when parens aren't balanced, but it's easy enough to account for either way: `/\([^()]* [^()]*\)/g`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `\([^()]+\)` matches everything between a pair of parentheses. That includes spaces, and any other character except (newline or) parentheses.

(Assuming a regex dialect where literal parens need to be escaped, and plus matches one or more repetitions. Whether a negated character class matches a newline is also dialect-specific.)

If (as you say in a comment) you require at least one space, that's easy to add. Rephrase: match an opening parenthesis character, zero or more non-space, non-parenthesis characters, one space, zero or more non-parenthesis characters (spaces are okay too) until the closing parenthesis.

```
\([^ ()]* [^())*\)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the problem is that I need a term that captures the brackets if and only if there is a space in it. If there is none, it shouldn't capture it.